# Is there an archive of old security updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, security

Is there any way to find previous versions of binary package updates that were posted to a security repository?

Specifically, I am looking for libssl-dev 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 for Jammy, because I'm trying to debug a core dump that happened on a system with that version of openssl installed.

The crash is in native code attached to a JVM, and Java's "jhsdb" tool is *very* finicky about shared library versions being exactly the same between the core dump and the running system.

However, the jammy-security repository only has 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.15.  For most purposes this is the right thing; you don't want versions with known vulnerabilities lying around.  But for corner cases like this (and other debugging and forensic purposes) having exact older versions would be a good idea.

Are they still available anywhere?

Comment: did you check Launchpad and the publishing history to find the .deb file there?

Comment: This might have what you're looking for:  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 .  Seems you can click on builds on the right.